# Ho to pass a generic value to a referenced interface method and extract a new type?

Tags: typescript

```
interface SomeInterface {
  someMethod<T>(): T
}

type SomeType = {
  [key in keyof SomeInterface]: ReturnType<SomeInterface[key]>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAsAFDLIDOWEAshGABboAmAPACoB8AFAEoAXMi4UAvhQpgAngAcUGbF3koAvCQpUA2gGsIM5KGT6Z6GGjp5IsRBAC6IgEpMArlBAqFHJbny2kPQN7HgkKIA)

Is it possible to use generic of the `someMethod` in the `SomeType` type? How?

I hoped for something like `ReturnType<(SomeInterface[key])<string>>`

But it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: You want `SomeType` to be `{someMethod: string}`? That's not going to be possible programmatically. TypeScript has [instantiation expressions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), so if you had a *value* `si` of type `SomeInterface` you could write `ReturnType<typeof si.someMethod<string>>` and it would work (and be `string`.  But there's no way to do this purely at the type level, and there's no way to abstract over possibly-generic methods in a mapped type.  So you could do [this](//tsplay.dev/WGVxkm) but it doesn't scale.

Comment: If you want me to write that up as an answer I can.  Otherwise, what am I missing?  Also, could you edit your mapped type so that the type parameter `key` is conventionally named like `K` (or `Key` I guess, but the convention `K` is more common)?  It's a generic type parameter and not a dummy key identifier, so it should be named as such to reduce confusion and distraction.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I think your first comment is an answer to my question. Feel free to write it as an answer :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript's type system lacks the expressiveness required to programmatically extract type parameters from [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function types.  For that we'd probably need either *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), or possibly *generic values* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574). Even with those features I'm not sure how one could use them to do what you want.   Right now this seems to be just beyond the language's abilities.

There are a few features which you could *try* to use, such as [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) or [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), but both of those require that you have a *value* of the relevant generic function type.  That is, you have to "drop down" from the type level to the value level to work with these features, and then try to "lift" the resulting value back up to the type level.  They can't really be abstracted, so you can't use them in  [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

The closest I could get here would be:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  someMethod<T>(): T
  otherMethod(): number;
}

declare const si: SomeInterface;

type SomeType = {
  [K in keyof SomeInterface]:
  K extends "someMethod" ? ReturnType<typeof si.someMethod<string>> :
  ReturnType<SomeInterface[K]>
}

/* type SomeType = {
    someMethod: string;
    otherMethod: number;
} */
```

Where we explicitly pretend to have a value `vi` of type `SomeInterface`, which is bad enough.  Then we need to explicitly grab its `someMethod` property in order to use an instantiation expression.  This explicit reference to `someMethod` would have to be repeated for each generic method of `SomeInterface`.  So at the end we get the right type, but it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

you can say that `SomeInterface` getting as an input generic.

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
  someMethod<T>(): T
}

type SomeType = {
  [key in keyof SomeInterface<string>]: ReturnType<SomeInterface<string>[key]>
}
```

You can even go one step further and make SomeType get an input generic.

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
  someMethod<T>(): T
}

type SomeType<T> = {
  [key in keyof SomeInterface<T>]: ReturnType<SomeInterface<T>[key]>
}
```

Comment: So, in this case the interface's generic overrides method generics? And they need to be compatible I assume?

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: This method doesn't use method's generic but the interface's "global" one. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxIA8AKshAB6QgAmAzsnWFKAOYB8yA3gLABQyRlggBZCGAAW6GqXJUItBiACumAEbR2ACgCUALmQl+AX378wATwAOKDNhLWUAXm79BAbQDWEC8lDJvC3QYNGE8SFhECCIAckgmGPYAXQM7XHxI4jiIBPYvHySTfiA – this shouldn't be possible. I hoped to be able to work with different generics per method.